# Paragraph Hyphenation with childrenElements in itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I need to add a lot of Text in Paragraph with change color, textSize,textRise etc. If I do as below, the hyphen does not work.

```
String s = "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus";
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("_testPdf/testHyph.pdf"));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A5);

      Paragraph p =  new Paragraph().
              setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "none", 2, 2));
        for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
            Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
            if(i%2==0)
                text.setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(0,0,0)).setFontSize(20);
            else
                text.setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(255,0,0)).setFontSize(15);


            p.add(text);
        }
      doc.add(p);
      doc.close();
```

if i do this, Hyphenation don't work
[image]

Comment: Hyphenation is done at the `Text` level, this is expected behavior in iText.

Comment: @Alexey Subach  Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Probably a single text with a *very* custom renderer which applies the variable text styles?

Comment: @ mkl is it a question? if is, yes need text styles for every Letters

Comment: @heavywar you can apply custom color and text rise on draw (after layout), but changing font size affects all the glyphs around so the look will be messy

Comment: @ Alexey Subach  There are no other ways?

Comment: @Alexey Subach , can i add the width of font size affects in advance ? Until triggered Hyphenation  ?

Comment: @ Alexey Subach how can i apply color or setRise after layout? i have to using ParagraphRenderer ?